# Access Update Query: Query does not include the specified expression as part of an aggregate function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to do the following: 
1. Put the count of each drivers' cancellation from the Ride table (IsCancelled = "Y") into the Driver table to keep track of how many cancellations each driver has made. 
2. Input the average rating of each driver into the Driver table - which is derived from the average of all DriverRating for that specific driver from the Ride table.

```
UPDATE Driver 

INNER JOIN ((Car 
INNER JOIN CarTypeAssignment ON Car.LicensePlateNo = CarTypeAssignment.LicensePlateNo) 
INNER JOIN Ride ON CarTypeAssignment.CarTypeAssignmentID = Ride.CarTypeAssignmentID) 

ON Driver.DriverLicenseNo = Car.DriverLicenseNo 

SET Driver.DriverCancellation = Count([Ride].[IsCancelled]), Driver.DriverRating = Avg([Ride].[DriverRating]);
```

I tried to execute the SQL code above in Microsoft Access, but got the following error message:

> Your query does not include the specified expression 'Driver Cancellation' as part of an aggregate function.

*P.s. I am unable to attach picture of my tables, so please ignore the INNER JOIN portion of the code - it should be correct.

Comment: Saving calculated data is usually unnecessary and can be dangerous, especially aggregate data. The saved data can get 'out of sync' with raw data. If you can calculate the value for an UPDATE, you can calculate whenever needed. Access won't even allow an UPDATE action SQL with aggregate functions (Sum, Count, etc) which need to be used in an aggregate (GROUP BY) query.

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE` doesn't support aggregation.  You need to use a subquery.

```
UPDATE Driver d INNER JOIN
       (SELECT DriverLicenseNo, 
               Count([Ride].IsCancelled) as cnt,
               Avg([Ride].[DriverRating]) as avg_rating
        FROM (Car as c INNER JOIN
              CarTypeAssignment as cta
              ON c.LicensePlateNo = cta.LicensePlateNo
             ) INNER JOIN
             Ride as r
             ON cta.CarTypeAssignmentID = r.CarTypeAssignmentID
       ) as c 
       ON d.DriverLicenseNo = c.DriverLicenseNo 
    SET d.DriverCancellation = cnt,
        d.DriverRating = avg_rating;
```